# Does Google Firestore cache documents and collections or does it always request new ones?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have a single page web application and I have NOT enabled offline persistence.

A component in this application has subscribed to a document using the `onSnapshot` function and recieves updates.

An other component in the same application instance reads the same document using the `get` function. Will firebase provide the same instance of the document, which is already loaded in the subscription? Or will it do a new request to the server?

A third component in the same application instance subscribes to the same document. Will this trigger new requests to the server?

What about reading and subscribing collections?

What about subscribing to a collection which is already subscribed, but the second subscription is called after narrowing results with the `where` function? Will Firestore reuse the already loaded complete collection and filter in my client instance? Or will it make server requests?

Comment: Witek: Does LeadDreamer's information help you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a rule, Firestore does maintain a local cache, *mostly* for latency/response, not for cost savings.  That said, if a document can be read from the cache, it will be, saving the read.  I wouldn't try to "design" it in, however; memory limits and other considerations mean *you* don't really know what's in the cache or not, and shouldn't know.

**IF** this performance/cost is important to you, it's better to combine Firestore with something like Redux (which I do) to maintain local "sets" of documents to reduce round-trip calls, and Listeners to keep Redux current.

Answer (score 0):

yes. Firebase stores documents and collections in cache memory. when you are offline you can access cache copy of data. also you can manage cache copy of documents and collections.

read this offical docs for more info

https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/enable-offline

Comment: The referenced document explains durable/persistent caching. This kicks in, when offline. But what when I am not offline? Or when offline persistence is disabled? Does Firestore cache subscribed documents in memory? Or do two subscriptions of the same document mean, that I am requesting (and paying) for them twice?

Comment: As a rule, Firestore does maintain a local cache, *mostly* for latency/response, not for cost savings.  That said, if a document can be read from the cache, it will be, saving the read.  I wouldn't try to "design" it in, however; memory limits and other considerations mean *you* don't really know what's in the cache or not, and shouldn't know.  **IF** this performance/cost is important to you, it's better to combine Firestore with something like Redux (which I do) to maintain local "sets" of documents to reduce round-trip calls, and Listeners to keep Redux current.